# Excel -> Find variable and reference cells next to them

Tags: excel, variables, search, reference

Thank you ahead of time for your responses.  I know the following can be done, but I am looking for the right words to use or reference pages to get this done.

It does not let me post an image, but an example:

I have the following:
VarA in A1, number for VarA in B1
VarB in A2, number for VarB in B2 
VarA in C5, number for VarA in D5
VarB in C6, number for VarB in D6

I am looking for a way to tell excel to "look through every cell on the spreadsheet that is "VarA" -> reference the number to the right of that variable" so I can get a total for the whole sheet for all of the numbers next to VarA.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: sorry, still new to the site.  thanks for the help.

Comment: In my other comment to wahwahwah, do you know if it is possible to use something like this with the =SUMIF function:   =SUMIF( anywhere in the spreadhseet, "VarA", look at the number to the right of that cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUMIF(A:A, "VarA",B:B)`

... This function takes a target range as its first parameter (A:A), a criteria as the second ("VarA",) and the range to sum as it's third (B:B.)

You can define these ranges to the exact rows and it will be more performant, or you can leave it as is at it will evaluate the entire columns.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  

What if VarA is in A1 , B5, and scattered throughout the random cells on one spreadsheet.  Is there something I can put in where it is something like:

=SUMIF( anywhere in the spreadhseet, "VarA", look at the number to the right of that cell)